# Is there a critical section race around error in case of non preemptive kernels?

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

I am reading from the book "Operating system concepts", which says that

> a non preemptive kernel is free from race around conditions on the kernel data structures, as only one process is active at a time

I want to ask

1. Is this true only for a single processor? Because if it is a multiprocessor system, then it could have multiple processes running concurrently, which could be accessing the same kernel data.
2. Is there any need (if it is possible) of using semaphores in a non preemptive kernel system?

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt: I believe what is intended is that, in a preemptive kernel, the kernel can preempt itself and so race conditions may occurs. In a non preemptive kernel is the program that yields, so the kernel cannot lock as there would be no one else that could change any internal structure of the kernel itself. On a MP system, it depends on how the process are scheduled on different processors: if only one process at time owns all the processors, we have the usual UP case, otherwise, multiple processes are active at the same time (so the need for locks).

Comment: The point of the sync primitives like semaphore is to put you on a wait while someone else finishes its work, but if you are the one in charge of relinquishing the CPU, you can't wait hoping that the kernel will preempt you, you simply give the CPU away for them to finish (you yield).

Comment: Okay, so in case of parallel processes running in case of a Non Preemptive kernel, we can say that the first process which enters the critical state using the semaphore will be the only one editing the critical section, and the other processes will be allowed entry into it (one by one) only after this present process has exited from the critical section. Hence the system is free from race around conditions. Have I understood this right?

Comment: Yes, I would say so.